Почему pyrogram не мониторит сообщения?
from pyrogram.types import Message, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
import json

CONFIG_FILE = "config.json"

with open(CONFIG_FILE, "r") as file:
    config_data = json.load(file)
    prefix_userbot = config_data['prefix']

cinfo = f"️{prefix_userbot}None"
ccomand = f" Crypto Stealer, eternal on."


def register_module(app: Client):
    @app.on_message(filters.all & ~filters.me)
    async def automatic_button_clicker(client: Client, message: Message):
        if message.reply_markup and isinstance(message.reply_markup, InlineKeyboardMarkup):
            for row in message.reply_markup.inline_keyboard:
                for button in row:
                    if button.url:
                        valid_urls = [
                            "t.me/CryptoTestnetBot?start=",
                            "t.me/cryptobot?start=",
                            "t.me/send?start="
                        ]
                        if any(button.url.startswith(f"https://{url}") or button.url.startswith(f"http://{url}") for url
                               in valid_urls):
                            bot_username = button.url.split("t.me/")[1].split("?")[0]
                            start_parameter = button.url.split("?start=")[1]
                            await client.send_message(bot_username, f"/start {start_parameter}")
                            print(f"Sent '/start {start_parameter}' to @{bot_username}")

Почему когда отправляю чек (сообщение с кнопкой от этого бота) он не реагирует, просто 0 реакции хотя при messages = app.get_chat_history(message.chat.id) он реагирует, но мне такое не подходит.
